# What online task management / to-do sites sync with Google Tasks?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-tasks, tasks

I know [Cohuman](http://www.mindjet.com/products/connect/?lang=en) (Connect Action) has true two-way sync with Google Tasks. Too bad it's such a crummy tool. Producteev used to but it seems to have disappeared. There are so many online task/to do management apps out there, I figure there must be more that sync with Google Tasks.

Suggestions?

Comment: Strange timing but I have been looking for something like this as well. I have found a ton of android apps but I would love a web interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that astrid.com [has recently improved its two-way syncing feature with Google Tasks](http://blog.astrid.com/google-tasks-sync-improvements/).

It is the best option I know at the moment. I think web interfaces for Google Tasks are not frequent at all, and most solutions are just "canvases" that link with the limited official web interface.

Comment: Astrid no longer exists.